# how to pass data from tableview to another tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using static `UITableView` to show profile of a customer.

It has SelectCountryCell to select country which, when clicked, opens new `UITableView` with country list.

When I select country from Country TableView, It should display in previous TableView's SelectCountryCell.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the static cells to outlets in your `UITableViewController` and put the profile syncing methods to the `- viewWillAppear` method.

When the user changes the country in the Country list the profile updates. After that when the user moves back to the `UITableViewController` instance with static content the profile data will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a delegate in your CityTableView and then define a method in this delegate.

You should realize this method in your CountryTableView.

Then you may get what you want.

I only offer you a thought. You should find the detail by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**MasterViewController.h**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <DetailProtocol> // Note this.

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *selectedCountry;

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.detailViewController.delegate = self; // THIS IS IMPORTANT...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}

// Note this -- It's a delegate method implementation
- (void)setCountry:(NSString *)country
{
    self.selectedCountry = country;
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@protocol DetailProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)setCountry:(NSString *)country;
@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <DetailProtocol> delegate; // Note this

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.delegate setCountry:[countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // Note this
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```